# Can you serve a drunk alcohol in Texas?

Tags: texas, alcohol

If a TABC certified bartender believes someone is inebriated, can they serve them alcohol in Texas? To what degree are you criminally and civilly liable for this transaction?

- If the patron gets in a wreck while intoxicated do you share civil liability?
- If the patron gets in a wreck while intoxicated and kills someone, are you criminally liable?
- If the patron does nothing criminal while intoxicated, is there anyway you can be held liable for merely serving?

And lastly,

- If the patron orders enough alcohol to get recklessly intoxicated but does so while totally sober and capable of consenting (such as ordering 5 shots), are you liable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the patron gets in a wreck while intoxicated do you share civil liability?

Yes, [Alcoholic Beverage Code Section 2.02](https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/AL/htm/AL.2.htm#2.02) creates a cause of action for this exact situation.

> If the patron gets in a wreck while intoxicated and kills someone, are you criminally liable?

You are criminally liable just for serving them, see below.  I don't know whether there are additional charges possible if death results.

> If the patron does nothing criminal while intoxicated, is there anyway you can be held liable for merely serving?

Yes, you are in violation of [Alcoholic Beverage Code Section 101.63](https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/AL/htm/AL.101.htm#101.63), a misdemeanor punishable by a fine of $100-$500 and up to one year in jail.  On a second offense, the fine increases to $500-$1000.

You may also have your TABC Seller-Server Certificate [revoked](https://texreg.sos.state.tx.us/public/readtac$ext.TacPage?sl=R&app=9&p_dir=&p_rloc=&p_tloc=&p_ploc=&pg=1&p_tac=&ti=16&pt=3&ch=50&rl=31).

> If the patron orders enough alcohol to get recklessly intoxicated but does so while totally sober and capable of consenting (such as ordering 5 shots), are you liable?

I have not yet been able to find an answer to this.